# Performance measurement on Android

Tags: java, android, performance, memory

i am looking for ways of measuring the performance of my Android application. In particular when a specific methods are called. Apparently, I can use time (time after - time before) t evaluate how quick and there therefore how fast it performed.

Does anyone know any other technique? i.e. showing how much processor is used.

Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) tool for this [as kabuko mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9689147/586489), note that this tool is also [accessable from Eclipse](http://gargengineer.blogspot.nl/2011/12/android-application-performance.html) and quite easy to use:

Run the App, go the the DDMS view, select the process to trace and click the "Start Method Profiling" button (tree arrows with a red dot). Perform actions you want to profile in the App and then click the same button again to stop tracing and Eclipse will show the trace to you.

[image: Start method profiling button]

Answer (score 3):

Android comes with a tool called TraceView which is useful for measuring this kind of thing. Read this doc on [profiling with Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html).